# "No overload takes 2 arguments" but IntelliSense shows overload with 2 arguments

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

I'm sorry if this has been asked before, I have searched for it but can't find anything that answers my confusion.

If I write the following code, I get a compiler error saying `No overload for method 'Contains' takes 2 arguments`, but IntelliSense suggests that there IS an overload that takes 2 arguments ([screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESTTg.png)):

```
string s = "Hello";
if (s.Contains('h', StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    Console.WriteLine("True!");
}
```

I'm passing a *char* as first argument and `StringComparer` implements `IEqualityComparer` so I don't get what is wrong.

Can anyone explain why I get an error?

Comment: If you look closely in you screenshot the equality compare expected is for `char` but you are using one for `string`.

Comment: but a `string` is also a `IEnumerable<char>`, right? So I should be able to call IEnumberable<char>.Contains(...), right?

Comment: @JohnnyMyMan Actually it's a `IEnumerable<char>`, but yes you can use that extension method but it expects a `IEqualityComparer<char>` and `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` is `IEqualityComparer<string>` instead.

Comment: @juharr Thanks a bunch!

Comment: One way would be: `if (s.Select(x => x.ToString()).Contains("h", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))`

Comment: What Johnny is describing above is a real phenomenon and still there in March 2019. My conclusion is that in my case one of the analyzers *version 2.6.3") is triggering a misleading advise concerning implementing string.Contains with two parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StringComparer implements `IEqualityComparer<string>` with type argument string, but the expected parameter is `IEqualityComparer<char>` with type argument char.
The types are still incompatible.

Have a read about generic type parameters:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters

Comment: But how come it doesn't say that my argument is wrong? Instead it says that the method doesn't exist. That's what confuses me I think

Comment: @JohnnyMyMan It normally does say which parameter is wrong, it seems that it's getting confused by the extension method

Comment: And the fact that there's a regular `string.Contains` method is also likely adding to the problem.

Comment: Ok, I think that makes sense to me. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnnyMyMan: juharr is correct. The error message is that no *overload* of `String.Contains` takes two arguments, and that is correct. Extension methods are not *overloads* in the traditional sense.